# Master branch is behind gh-pages branch

Tags: git

The problem is that my master branch is 2 days behind my gh-pages.

Initially I did:

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m "initial commit"
git checkout gh-pages
git remote add origin https://... 
git subtree push --prefix dist origin gh-pages
```

Then I committed and pushed changes to this branch several times, but I never pushed any changes to my master branch.

Now after:

```
git checkout master
git show
```

I see that on this branch I still see only the initial commit. But I cannot 'git add .' or 'commit' any new files or changes. I see the message that everything is up-to-date.

The question is: how do I update my master branch?

I am pretty new at git, hope for your patience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my humble opinion, you shouldn't have rushed into `git subtree` from the beginning. This is a very particular use case of Git, which is independent from branching system. Moreover, when doing `git checkout gh-pages`, you try to switch from branch *master* (by default) to *gh-pages*, which doesn't exist yet since just have created your repository (using `git init`). This should have failed with a error message.

> The question is: how do I update my master branch?

In normal conditions, you would have merged the `gh-pages` branch into the *master* one, using :

```
git checkout master
git merge gh-pages
```

… but I'm pretty sure this is **NOT** what you'll need to do in your current conditions. In particular, I understand that your local repository was not empty at the beginning but if you have added a remote repository, did this one already exist before ? If yes, and if they was no previous work in your local repository, maybe you should have used `git clone` instead.

In any case, try to do a

```
git remote update
```

… first, to synchronize the state of your local repository with the remote one (this won't affect you working directory).